# Add static new record to p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am new in JSF with Primefaces. How to add new static record in `<p:dataTable>`? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical to just add a new item to the collection behind `<p:dataTable value>`? On an unrelated note, please stop formatting non-code as code. API/library/framework names like "JSF" and "PrimeFaces" are not code.

Comment: I couldn't understand. please explain clearly..

Comment: The `<p:dataTable>` generates its HTML output based on a `List<Something>`. In plain Java, how would you add a new item to a `List<Something>`?